# Get error message from a throw error NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, try-catch, getmessage

I need to insert a log error in my db with the error.

```
mysql.query(sql_log, [sucess], function (err, result) {
     if (err){ 
        mysql.rollback(function() {
           throw err;
        });
      }
});
```

I need get err.message

Answer (score 0):

just `console.log(err);` after if condition.

```
mysql.query(sql_log, [sucess], function (err, result) {
 if (err){ 
console.log(err);
    mysql.rollback(function() {
       throw err;
    });
  }});
```

Comment: Yes i know but i need something like console.log(err.msg);